# how to remove angle brackets and data types from sql query from the values fields in sql server

Tags: sql-server

i want to generate insert query from the sql server from table . but im getting some unwanted code in sql query . how to trim or remove brackets and data type values. is there any short cut method to write insert query from the table

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_invoice]
           ([Id]
           ,[InvoiceNo]
           ,[InvoiceNoDated]
           ,[DeliveryNote]
           ,[Despatch Doc. No]
           ,[DespatchDated]
           ,[termsofdelivery]
           ,[ItemCodeandDescription]
           ,[quantity]
           ,[unitprice]
           ,[totalpriceexcludingtax]
           ,[taxPrice]
           ,[TotalPriceIncludingTax]
           ,[GrandTotal])
     VALUES
           (<Id, int,>
           ,<InvoiceNo, varchar(50),>
           ,<InvoiceNoDated, varchar(50),>
           ,<DeliveryNote, varchar(max),>
           ,<Despatch Doc. No, varchar(50),>
           ,<DespatchDated, varchar(50),>
           ,<termsofdelivery, varchar(50),>
           ,<ItemCodeandDescription, varchar(max),>
           ,<quantity, int,>
           ,<unitprice, varchar(50),>
           ,<totalpriceexcludingtax, varchar(50),>
           ,<taxPrice, varchar(50),>
           ,<TotalPriceIncludingTax, varchar(50),>
           ,<GrandTotal, varchar(50),>)
GO
```

Comment: You can use a notepad tool like `Notepad++` and so on ;).

Comment: What tool did you use to generate this?

Comment: im using sql sever management studio,,,script table as... insert to

Comment: i m writing c# code where i cannot write like this ..compilation error coming.

Comment: how you get this "<Id, int,>"? and are you want value as 'id,int' with single quotes to insert ?

Comment: yes sorry for asking wrong question. i have to manually write the variables...like 'txtid'

Comment: can we remove square brackets from insert fields...

Comment: Mouse and keyboard works well for me.

Comment: If you remove brackets, the `[Despatch Doc. No]` won't run. They are called [Delimited Identifiers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: In SSMS pressing SHIFT + M will open the "Specify Values for Template Parameters" dialog.  This is a handy find and replace for text in the format <Param_Name, Param_Type, Value>.

Comment: Oh god! I can't believe this is a big in SQL Server Management studio. When did this bug creep in and who do we contact at Microsoft to get it fixed? This is horrible! I'm experiencing the same problem

Comment: This bug has been around for three years? What?

Answer (score 2):

Both SSMS (where I'd imagine you're getting this from) and Visual Studio have, for quite some time, supported Find & Replace with regular expressions.

A Find & Replace specifying `\<[^\>]+\>` as the Find Text, using the Regular Expressions Find Option, and specifying an empty string as the Replace Text should quickly sort this out.

Unfortunately, there's no option to prevent SSMS from generating these [template parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179334(v=sql.105).aspx). Most people find them a useful reminder, at times, of the required data types, and it's usually quite quick to just highlight each one before typing the replacement value you want.